# Is it possible to overload a generic method by input type?

Tags: c#, .net

In a nutshell, I'm hoping there is some way to accomplish this API style:

```
Repo repo = new Repo();
List<Car> cars = repo.All<Car>();
List<Truck> trucks = repo.All<Truck>();
```

---

I have a `Repo` object that retrieves objects from a database.  Currently it works like this:

```
Repo repo = new Repo();
List<Car> cars = repo.Cars.All();
List<Truck> trucks = repo.Trucks.All();
```

Where the `Repo` class is:

```
class Repo {
    List<Car> Cars = new CarRepo();
    List<Truck> Trucks = new TruckRepo();
}
```

Where `CarRepo` and `TruckRepo` each contain:

```
interface IRepo<T> {
    List<T> All();
}

class CarRepo : IRepo<Car> {
    List<Car> All() => new List<Car>() { };
}
// Same for TruckRepo
```

Unfortunately, if I wanted to add a new collection of vehicles to this pattern, I would need to create a new list on the `Repo` object.  In this contrived example, that's no big deal, but this god-`Repo` object could grow quite large in an application with many sub-repos.  What I'd rather have is the `Repo` class implement `All` directly.

#### This is the closest I've come:

```
interface IRepo<T>
{
    List<T> All<T>();
}

partial class Repo {}

partial class Repo : IRepo<Car>
{
    public List<Car> All<Car>() => new List<Car>() { };
}

partial class Repo : IRepo<Truck>
{
    public List<Truck> All<Truck>() => new List<Truck>() { };
}

// Usage:
Repo repo = new Repo();
List<Car> cars = repo.All<Car>();
```

This adds the `All<>` method to `Repo`, but due to a few problems I don't know the solution for, it can't even compile.

- `All<>` is implemented twice for `Repo` since types don't affect the actual method signature
- The second `T` in `List<T> All<T>` is redundant
- In `List<Car> All<Car>`, `Car` is just another way of writing `T`, and does not refer to the actual `Car` class

This is the first time I've delved into proper generics in C# - is this even possible?

Comment: Removed the C# 6 tag as the problem is not related to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is NOT what partial classes are to be used for.  The specific use of the partial class is to split the functionality of the class between multiple files.

When utilizing generics, the purpose is to define common, ***core*** functionality that can then be reused by multiple concrete types.

As a result, you should create a new concrete repository class for each type.

```
interface IRepo<T>
{
    List<T> All<T>();
}

class CarRepo : IRepo<Car>
{
    public List<Car> All<Car>() => new List<Car>() { };
}

class TruckRepo : IRepo<Truck>
{
    public List<Truck> All<Truck>() => new List<Truck>() { };
}

public class Truck { }
public class Car { }
```

Comment: This is how I have it working now - I was hoping there was a way to consolidate all the `xRepo`s so I could query by type instead of having to instantiate 20 repos for all my objects.  If this is how it has to be done though, thank you!

Comment: If you drive this behavior via Dependency Injection, particularly with a powerful IoC, you can eliminate the need to directly instantiate the repos yourself.  That said, I would certainly recommend avoiding using partial classes to try to solve this problem.

Comment: I'll look into IoC, thank you for the suggestion!  Mind if I keep the question open for a bit to see some other answers?

Comment: Not at all!  Hopefully it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an approach like this may helps you:

```
interface IRepo<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> All();
}

class Repo : IRepo<Car>, IRepo<Truck>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> All<T>()
    {
        if (this is IRepo<T>)
            return (this as IRepo<T>).All();

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    IEnumerable<Truck> IRepo<Truck>.All() => new List<Truck>();  //Implemented explicitly

    IEnumerable<Car> IRepo<Car>.All() => new List<Car>();        //Implemented explicitly
}
```

Doing this you can implement as many `IRepo` as you want, and make the calls like `repo.All<Type>()`.

Something like this:

```
var repo = new Repo();

var trucks = repo.All<Truck>();
var cars = repo.All<Car>();
var motors = repo.All<Motorcycle>(); //throws NotSupportedException
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider to constrain the repo items themselves (`Car`, `Truck`, etc.) with an interface `IRepoItem`, and make Repo a non-generic class with the `All<T>()` method being generic, using a constraint on the type of item `All<T>()` can return to that interface, e.g.: `All<T>() where T : IRepoItem`

Example code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IRepo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var repo = new Repo();

            var carList = repo.All<Car>(); // ok
            var truckList = repo.All<Truck>(); // ok
            //var bananas = repo.All<Banana>(); // compiler error
        }
    }

    public class Repo
    {
        public List<T> All<T>() where T : IRepoItem
        {
            return new List<T>();
        }
    }

    public interface IRepoItem { }
    public class Car : IRepoItem { }
    public class Truck : IRepoItem { }
    public class Banana { } // not an IRepoItem
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the `Car` and `Truck` classes - they are from another service that I am connecting to.  Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: @ScottKaye No worries, thought I would provide another way to look at the problem. If you really wanted to, you can write wrapper classes that implement the `IRepoItem` interface for the objects that you receive from the service and still have one Repo class. Though in that case, either way, you are going to do *something* and recompile when new types of repo items become available. So it becomes kind of pointless exercise in semantics at that point :) The chosen answer provides a good solution and excellent explanation. Most importantly you now know what partial classes are NOT designed for!